# If $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then the inverse to $(AB)^T$ is equal to $( A^{-1})^T(B^{-1})^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then the inverse to $(AB)^T$ is equal to $(A^{-1})^T(B^{-1})^T$. No luck so far - some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $(A^{T})^{-1}$ = $(A^{-1})^{T}$
- $(AB)^{T}$=$B^TA^T$
- $(AB)^{-1}$=$B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

$$(AB)^T = (B^T)(A^T)$$

$$((B^T)(A^T))^{-1}$$

$$(A^T)^{-1}(B^T)^{-1}$$

$$(A^{-1})^T(B^{-1})^T$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards